# {self.tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-command"} error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write calculator code which contains only plus mode and minus mode and BMI calculator. I've tried everything I know so far but I can't figure it out that why my code is unable to use

Here is my Bmi code:

```
from tkinter import  *
def bmi():
    kg = int(box1.get())
    m = int(box2.get())
    result =(kg)/(m^2)
    result.configure(result).grid(row=2,column=1)
    return

root = Tk()
root.option_add("*font", "impact 16")
Label(root, text= "wight(kg.)").grid(row=0,column=0)
box1 = Entry(root).grid(row=0,column=1)
Label(root, text= "hight(m.)").grid(row=1,column=0)
box2 = Entry(root).grid(row=1,column=1)
Label(root, text= "BMI",command=bmi).grid(row=2,column=0)
Button(root, text= "calculate").grid(row=3,columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

and there is my calculator code

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_output():
    number = int(number1_input.get())
    if number == 1:
        output_label.configure(text="plus")
        number0_ask = tk.Label(master=window, text='input first number')
        number0_input = tk.Entry(master=window,width= 15)
        number2_ask = tk.Label(master=window, text='input second number')
        number2_input = tk.Entry(master=window, width=15)
        sum = int(number0_input)+int(number2_input)
        output_label2.configure(sum)
    elif number == 2:
        output_label.configure(text="plus")
        number0_ask = tk.Label(master=window, text='input first number')
        number0_input = tk.Entry(master=window, width=15)
        number2_ask = tk.Label(master=window, text='input second number')
        number2_input = tk.Entry(master=window, width=15)
        sum = int(number0_input) + int(number2_input)
        output_label2.configure(sum)
    else:
        output_label2.configure("none of our program")

    return

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("calulator")
window.minsize(width=400, height=400)

tittle_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="enter order 1 for plus 2 for minus")
tittle_label.pack(pady=20)

number1_input = tk.Entry(master=window, width=15)
number1_input.pack(pady=20)

go_button = tk.Button(master=window, text="result", command=show_output, width=15,
                      height=2)
go_button.pack(pady=20)

output_label = tk.Label(master=window)
output_label.pack(pady=20)
output_label2 = tk.Label(master=window)
output_label2.pack(pady=20)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What tests did you conduct on your code components? What part is failing? When?

Comment: Labels do not have a `command=` option.  I think you intended for that `command=bmi` to apply to the following Button.